# isEqualToComparingFieldByField is failing but isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively is passing

Tags: java, rest-assured, assertj

I am writing a test using rest-assured to test an API. I have the expected response stored as a String that I convert to an object using google gson and then I use assertj's isEqualToComparingFieldByField to assert that the objects are equal.

Even though the objects fields values are identical the test is failing.What is very strange is that when i call isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively the test passes? I would be Ok with using isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively  but for my next test I need to use isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields.

Here is the exception I get when calling isEqualToComparingFieldByField.

> Expecting values:
>          <[test.api.pojo.template.Template@42cc420b,
>           test.api.pojo.template.Status@6f2d3391]>
>       in fields:
>         <["template", "status"]>
>       but were:
>         <[test.api.pojo.template.Template@71b0289b,
>           test.api.pojo.template.Status@ae3c140]>
>       in test.api.pojo.template.TemplateResponse@2c9cafa5>.

and here is the code for the test

```java
RequestSpecification request = given()
            .spec(spec)
            .pathParam("name", "abc");

Response response = request.when().get(ENDPOINT_GET_TEMPLATE);

String expectedResponseStr =  "{ \"id\": 1247,"
    + "\"versionNumber\": 0,"
    + "\"template\": {";//...

String actualResponseStr = response.asString();
assertThat(actualResponseStr).isEqualTo(expectedResponseStr); //this passes 


TemplateResponse expectedResponseObj = convertToObj(expectedResponseStr, TemplateResponse.class);
TemplateResponse actualResponseObj = response.then().extract().as(TemplateResponse.class);

assertThat(actualResponseObj)
    .isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(expectedResponseObj); //this passes

assertThat(actualResponseObj)
    .isEqualToComparingFieldByField(expectedResponseObj); //this fails with
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isEqualToComparingFieldByField` will use fields `equals` method which I suspect are not overridden in `Status` and `Template`, this means that for the test to pass they must be the same reference (they are not according to the error message).

On the other hand, `isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively` only uses `equals` methods when they are overridden otherwise it compares fields by fields, the test passesas actual `Status` / `Template`  and expected ones have the same fields values.

Comment: ahh I assumed the name FieldByField meant it was comparing fields not references. I see that that only applies to the fields in the object that are primitives, objects in the objects are done by equals. Thank you very much

Comment: FYI Assert Core 3.12.0 provides a much improved recursive comparison https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison